# What is the difference between the Oracle DB Adapter and the Oracle E-Business Suite Adapter?

Tags: oracle, biztalk

What are the differences between the Oracle DB Adapter and the Oracle E-Business Suite Adapter?

Which situations would suit one over the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle DB adapter is a classic database adapter used to connect to Oracle database (similar to SQL adapter used to connect to Microsoft SQL Server)

Whereas Oracle E-Business Suite adapter is used to connect to Oracle E-Business Suite, which is suite of global applications ex: Customer Relationship Management, Order management, Channel Revenue marketing etc [link](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/applications/ebusiness/overview/index.html). It's something similar (not exactly) like Microsoft Dynamics CRM Adapter

Comment: Just as an aside, what about the E-Business adapter is specific to the E-Business Suite?